# A strange typeclass in Haskell. what's "class (Eq e, GenExpr e, MonadRandom m) => GenProg m e | e -> m where"

Tags: haskell, typeclass

```
class (Eq e, GenExpr e, MonadRandom m) => GenProg m e | e -> m where
```

Excactly, I can't understand this **GenProg m e | e -> m**

I guess GenProg is a constructor.

does that means: the one whose pattern matched **GenProg m e** or **e -> m**, whose instance can be defined ?

by the way, where can i get all syntax in haskell?

Comment: [Keywords](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Keywords#.7C). [Language spec](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Language_and_library_specification).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a multiparameter type class with a functional dependency. `GenProg` is the name of the class, the two parameters are `m` (which has to be an instance of `MonadRandom`) and `e` (which has to be an instance of `Eq` and `GenExpr`). Then the `|` separates the instance head from the functional dependency `e -> m`, which says that the type `e` in an instance determines the type constructor `m`, in other words, for any type `e` there can be at most one `m` such that an

```
instance GenProg m e where ...
```

appears in a valid programme. (I.e., if there is more than one such instance declaration with the same `e`, there will be a compilation error.)

Comment: So it's **m e** or **e -> m**. Not **GenProg m e** or **e -> m**.
thanks

Comment: @user20100 no, it's not an "or" at all. The `|` is just a separator, part of a syntax for [http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Functional_dependency].